# How do I determine which subclass of a parent to instantiate based on certain criterias?

Tags: php

I'm going to try to go as in depth as possible to explain my idea of my class model to (hopefully) give a better basis for potential answers.

I've built a class that parses data from an application that share a common layout presented either in a txt file or an html file, but has dynamic data. I decided to try building it with a model where data handlers inherit the parser class.

The parser class parses the exported data and creates a multidimensional `$this->parsed` array. A subclass must then handle the data, and in some cases where the data is similar but laid out differently, other classes inherits the subclass. An example of this would be 1) a list of employees 2) a detailed view of one employee. In this case, the subclass `Employee` holds a multidimensional array of the handled data and has common methods for things like calculating age, etc. Since the exported data would be laid out differently (in case 1 a list of several employees, case 2 just one employee), I've written two more classes.

This could be the `$this->parsed` data array for a list of employees

```
$parsed[0][0] = Name
$parsed[0][1] = D.O.B.
$parsed[0][2] = E-mail address
$parsed[0][3] = Department
$parsed[1][0] = John Smith
$parsed[1][1] = 1980-3-5
$parsed[1][2] = john@smith.com
$parsed[1][3] = Economics
$parsed[2][0] = Jane Smith
$parsed[2][1] = 1964-1-12
$parsed[2][2] = jane@smith.com
$parsed[2][3] = PR
```

And the `$this->parsed` data for a detailed view of an employee

```
$parsed[0][0] = Name
$parsed[0][1] = John Smith
$parsed[1][0] = D.O.B.
$parsed[1][1] = 1980-3-5
$parsed[2][0] = E-mail address
$parsed[2][1] = john@smith.com
$parsed[3][0] = Department
$parsed[3][1] = Economics
```

Since the data is similar, I have an Employee class that extends the Parser class

```
abstract class Employee extends Parser {

    $handledData = array();

    abstract public function Populate();

    public function CalculateAge($employeePointer = 0) {

        $dob = $this->handledData[$employeePointer]['dob'];
        // Calculate...

    }

}
```

And since the parsed data is laid out differently, I use two subclasses that reads the `$this->parsed` array differently and sets the data to $handledData accordingly

```
class EmployeeListView extends Employee {

    public function Populate() {

        array_shift($this->parsed); // Remove the "header row"

        foreach ($this->parsed as $employeeArray) {

            list($name, $dob, $email, $dep) = $employeeArray;
            $this->handledData[] = array('name' => $name, 'dob' => $dob, 'email' => $email, 'dep' => $dep);

        }

    }

}
```

I use a similar process for the detailed view, but I think the idea is clear so I won't write an example of that.

I stumbled upon a problem using this layout. Since the exported data is dynamic, it will come in several forms. Although not infinite, the amount of variations may be as high as 100 if not more. For now in these two classes I've written `Validate()` methods that takes the size of the `$this->parsed` array recursively and checks its contents to validate the data is supposed to be handled by that class. That works well as long as I know specifically which class to use. However, I'd like my users to be able to upload files to the parser without having to spend time scrolling through a huge list of potential handler classes to find which one is suited for the file they upload.

How can I dynamically pick which subclass to use? I could possibly do something like this:

```
$buffer = file_get_contents($uploadedFile);
$classes = array('EmployeeListView', 'EmployeeDetailView');
foreach ($classes as $className) {
    $loadedClass = new $className();
    $loadedClass->Parse($buffer);
    if ($loadedClass->Validate() === true) { $found = true; break; }
}

if (!$found) { die("Unable to properly parse the uploaded file."); }
```

However, this way of doing things doesn't really sit well with me, and I'm sure there's a better way of doing it.

Hope I made myself clear.

Comment: You say the data is dynamic. What do you mean with this? That it could have different number of columns? In this case, will you always get a first row with the name of the columns?

Comment: @juanreyesv Basically that they differ both in rows and columns. And yes, different listed views has another row of headers. Each set provides a way to determine what data is in it by using headers. Either with all headers in a single row, or with a data layout of header in col. 1 and dataset in cols 2..n. My Validate() just looks for the max amount (width) of cols, and height (rows) while making sure every _expected_ header and its data is found.